# Unable to send 2 pywin32 emails within one program runtime

Tags: python, email, pywin32

So I have the ability to open outlook and insert all the needed values to create a draft of an email, however, when I reopen the window and attempt to send another email it gives met this error.

```
    self.mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
File "<COMObject Outlook.Application>", line 2, in CreateItem
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)
```

Is it the way I call it or is it the way this pywin32 works, how would I go about resolving this issue to the point where i can send as much emails, using the same code? Replacing self.mailItem.Display() with self.mailItem.Send(), allows me to send the multiple I desire however I want the user to edit any composed email before sending it. thus this not being a option.

my email class

```
import win32com.client as win32
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

class emailComposition():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        self.mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
        self.mailItem.Sensitivity  = 2
        attachment = self.mailItem.Attachments.Add("C:\\Users\\----\Desktop\\Krypt\\Images\\Logos\\Logo1.png")
        attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1")

    def setSubject(self, subj):
        self.mailItem.Subject = subj

    def setSender(self, senderEmail):
        self.sender = senderEmail

    def setRecipient(self, recipientEmail, recipientName):
        self.mailItem.To = recipientEmail
        self.rName = recipientName
        
    def setText(self, ItemList):    
        items = "<br>&bull; xyz <br>&bull; xyz"
        # still need to do something with the ItemList, removing it has no effect on the error outcome! 
        self.mailItem.HTMLBody = "<p>Good Day " + self.rName + " <br>Could you please send me a quote on the following: " + items + " </p> <p>Thanks</p><img src=""cid:MyId1"" width=""100"" height=""100"" >"

    def displayEmail(self):
        try:
            self.mailItem._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, olNS.Accounts.Item(self.sender)))
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Unregistered email")
            msg.setInformativeText("""The email provided isn't a registered email within outlook.\nA default email will be used.""")
            msg.setWindowTitle("Krypt")
            msg.exec_()
        self.mailItem.Display()
```

Code i use to call this class, all of it is in a button press connect

```
    def createEmail(self):
        input = self.ui.tblQuoteItems.item(0, 0)
        if input is not None:
            if self.ui.edtSupplier.text() != "" and self.ui.edtSupplierRep.text() != "": 
                x = emailComposition()
                x.setRecipient(self.ui.edtSupplierEmail.text(), self.ui.edtSupplierRep.text())
                x.setSubject("Official Quote")
                x.setSender(self.ui.edtUserEmail.text())
                self.read() #Loads self.itemList with needed items
                x.setText(self.itemList)
                x.displayEmail()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a `Namespace` and any standard folder reference after creating a new Outlook Application instance in the code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Read more about that in the [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa209963(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Also you may find the [Application Shutdown Changes in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd239276(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article helpful.